# VirtualBox - Ubuntu 16.04 Guest no Internet access with chome with NAT

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

I have a virtual machine with a Ubuntu 16.04 guest and two network interfaces

- First interface: NAT

[image]

- Second interface: Bridge

[image]

I want to access the guest from my host and I want to access a second ethernet device from the guest. The device is connected with the host over a switch. I can ping the host, the external device and `8.8.8.8`with my current setup from the guest, but I don´t have any internet access (chrome stucks at "resolving host").

[image]

When I deactivate the bridge the internet access does work, but not with the active bridge.

`ifconfig` gives me the following output
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Probably the second (bridge) interface is creating an entry in `/etc/resolv.conf` with a bad DNS server, or pointing to a DNS server that can not reach the internet.

Comment: It was the right tip. Thank you. It works after changing the nameserver to `8.8.8.8` by hand. How can I set this automatically?

Comment: Okay, I solve the problem with the nameserver option in the network settings :)

Comment: Maybe you can write up what you learned as an answer to the question, explaining why it went wrong and where you made changes to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, but I want test it first, because the first solution doesn´t work with apt.
I have opened the network settings in ubuntu (Desktop -> Edit Connections -> Select the NAT interface -> Edit -> IPv4-Settings -> add `8.8.8.8, 8.8.8.4` in the field "Additional DNS-Server"

This works with chrome and apt. Modify the DNS-Server by hand over resolve.conf doens´t work for apt, but with chrome...don´t understand why, but this solution is a little bit better than the "hacky" way :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add this in the network settings

[image]

I can access the internet, my host and the external device with these settings and the network configuration from above.